# Unable to print form in SharpDevelop 4.4.2

Tags: vb.net, sharpdevelop

I'm building a vb.net project in SharpDevelop 4.4.2.

I'm trying to print a form, using the **PrintDialog** printing tool.

When clicking "Print" on a menu dropdown, it brings up the Print Dialog fine, I select my printer and click "Print", but nothing happens. The form is still open, no errors appear, it's as if the code does nothing:

```
Sub PrintToolStripMenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Print current form
    printDialog1.ShowDialog
End Sub
```

Comment: The `PrintDialog` doesn't do any printing. It is a `PrintDocument` that does the printing. If you don't have a `PrintDocument` then you're not printing.

Comment: You should process the output of `printDialog1` and actually then execute printing.

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated!